# flex/bison fixing memory leaks with unexpected tokens

Tags: memory-leaks, bison, flex-lexer

I have a flex bison application.  For a few of my tokens, I copy out the yytext from flex using strdup.  This works great except when there is an error of an unexpected token.

simple example

```
flex.l:
...
[a-zA-Z0-9]+ { lval.string = strdup(yytext); return IDENT };
[\{\}]       { return yytext[0] };
...
```

and

```
parse.y
...
%destructor { free($$); } IDENT
%destructor { free($$->name); free($$->type); free($$); } tag
...
tag: IDENT '{' IDENT '}'
     {
         struct tag *mytag = malloc(sizeof(struct tag));
         mytag->name = $1;
         mytag->type = $3;
         $<tag>$ = mytag;
      }
...
```

Now suppose I hand it the input:

```
blah blah blah
```

The lexer will send up the first IDENT token, which gets pushed onto the stack.  After the first token it's expecting a bracket token, but instead gets another IDENT token.  This is a syntax error.  The destructor will be called on the *first* IDENT token, but *not* on the second one (the unexpected one).  I haven't been able to find a way to destruct the unexpected token.  Does anyone know how I should do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that appropriate use of the 'error' token in flex prompts it to correctly call the destructor function.  Go me!

```
parse.y
...
%destructor { free($$); } IDENT
%destructor { free($$->name); free($$->type); free($$); } tag
...
tags: tag tags | error tags | ;

tag: IDENT '{' IDENT '}'
     {
         struct tag *mytag = malloc(sizeof(struct tag));
         mytag->name = $1;
         mytag->type = $3;
         $<tag>$ = mytag;
     }
...
```